# Auto generating wsdl using DefaultWsdl11Definition

Tags: spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I have a problem with auto generating wsdl using DefaultWsdl11Definition

ContactServiceOperations.xsd

```
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://com/blog/samples/webservices/contactservice"
xmlns:Contact="http://webservices.samples.blog.com" targetNamespace="http://com/blog/samples/webservices/Contact"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:import namespace="http://webservices.samples.blog.com"
    schemaLocation="Contact.xsd" />
<xsd:element name="ContactRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:integer" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ContactResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Contact" type="Contact:Contact" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<sws:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="*" />

<bean id="ContactService"
    class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="schemaCollection">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
            <property name="inline" value="true" />
            <property name="xsds">
                <list>
                    <value>/xsd/ContactServiceOperations.xsd</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="portTypeName" value="ContactService" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="http://localhost:8080/SpringWS/ContactService/" />
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
     </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>  
       <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
       <init-param>  
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>  
            <param-value>true</param-value>  
       </init-param>  
       <init-param>  
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
            <param-value></param-value>  
       </init-param>  
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
       <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>  
       <url-pattern>/ContactService/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I can start Tomcat without errors. Then, I access to this URL:
`http://localhost:8080/SpringWS/ContactService/contactService.wsdl`
And browser show a blank page instead of generated wsdl.

Maybe I have something wrong in configuration. Any idea for help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

corrected this, ContactService.wsdl

```
localhost:8080/SpringWS/ContactService/ContactService.wsdl
```

Comment: I tried and I got a blank page (nothing appeared on my browser). Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your web.xml file. Try to have different context files for DispatcherServlet and MessageDispatcherServlet .

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

.....

....

```
<servlet>  
   <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>  
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
   <init-param>  
       <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springws-config.xml</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
 </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience while running the Spring Boot demos. If your problem is anything like mine then it *is* working. Spring sends the wsdl with the xml header i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><wsdl:definitions ...
```

I'm using Firefox and it flashes the wsdl before showing a blank screen. So viewing the source of the page showed the wsdl file in full.

There is a simple downloadable example of doing this using Spring Boot annotations:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-webservices

Comment: The link above is broken. Here is a link to spring ws related example codes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples